# Не работает стиль

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть два стиля, второй добавляется через js при нажатии на кнопку. Стиль добавляется, но блок не отображается

```
    .text__phrase-result {
    display: none;
    max-width: 750px;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(240, 235, 235);
}                                                                          

   .text__phrase-result_active {
    display: flex;
    }
```

[image: Стиль добавился, но блок не появился]

Comment: можно воспроизводимый пример?

Comment: у вас нигде больше стили для этого класса не переопределяет?

Comment: У класса "text__phrase-result_active", нет скрытого родителя?

Comment: ```.text__phrase-result_active {
    display: flex !important;
    }``` или ```.text__phrase-result.text__phrase-result_active {
    display: flex;
    }```

Comment: https://codepen.io/niceguyg/pen/RwGZjvY

Comment: Когда идёт клик на кнопку "исправить" добавляется класс text__phrase-result_active к соответствующему блоку с классом  text__phrase-result

Answer (score 0):

Не должно быть трудностей

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="text__phrase-result">asd</div>

  <div id="id">qw</div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#id').click(function() {
      $('.text__phrase-result').toggleClass('text__phrase-result_active');
    });
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .text__phrase-result {
      display: none;
      max-width: 750px;
      flex-direction: column;
      margin: auto;
      margin-top: 50px;
      background-color: rgb(240, 235, 235);
    }
    
    .text__phrase-result_active {
      display: flex;
    }
  </style>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Извините, а у меня написан такой же код на javascript без jquery, и без toggle